# rake assets:precompile not working (Rails 3.1.3 edition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, sass, asset-pipeline

After review, this question has been asked [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701010/rails-3-1-using-images-under-app-assets-images-subdirectory), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048164/file-png-isnt-precompiled), [many](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sass-rails%203.1%20rake%20aborted%20image%20assets%20precompile%20%20rails%203.1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frails%2Frails%2Fissues%2F2765&ei=hu3gTvqILsf30gHawMiZBw&usg=AFQjCNGoZyb1Dd45AgEYd6ioNLCNP2sXCg&sig2=CU8q5CgqXN7V7ZQ2fE7VAg) times. Yet I still don't grok why `rake assets:precompile` fails.

I can view the following results from my browser using local server (e.g. thin):

```
body{
@include background-image(image-url('my_image.png'));
background-repeat: repeat;
    ...
    ...
}
```

(NOTE: image-path doesn't seem to work at all and I'm using thoughtbot bourbon as SCSS lib)

Yet every time I run precompile I get the following (short trace):

```
rake aborted!
images/my_image.png isn't precompiled
(in /path/to/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647691/ruby-on-rails-3-1-assetsprecompile-and-images) suggests that I change my production.rb file, which I did and it compiled my image and rake now complains that I have an undefined mixin `'border-radius'`. Perhaps this was the next exception, but I am not so sure. And everything works locally.

Rails Guides (3.1.3) explicitly states setting the value to **true**

```
'uses more memory, performs poorer than the default and is not recommended'
```

So now I have two problems. Performance downgrade and my SCSS library now has undefined mixins.

I would like to solve the production deployment issue resulting from `rake assets:precompile`. My Gemfile asset group looks like this:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'zurb-foundation'
  gem 'bourbon' 
 end
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I can't figure out why it's failing to find the bourbon mixin in production.

Comment: I did not. I upgraded to 3.2.x and it worked w latest bourbon gem.

Answer (score 2):

If you go with the assets:precompile option, you should use `@import` statements in every stylesheet you use a mixin.

e.g.

Let's say you have a custom mixin in `app/assets/stylesheets/partials/_mixins.css.scss` that you use in a stylesheet, you should add

```
@import "partials/mixins";
```

to that stylesheet.

I know, is shouldn't be like that, but as for now, I haven't found any other way.

Comment: thanks @joiggama. I in fact already have that scheme in place bc of bourbon. still no luck

Answer (score 0):

The image-path helper assumes the `images` part of the path so remove that (and the slash) and it should start working.

Comment: `image-url('file_name.png')` nor `image-path('file_name.png')` provide the desired result (asset precompilation)

Comment: where it he file actually located (from app down)

Comment: Precompile does bail at the first error. The fact that you get an undefined mixin suggests that something else is amis, but I can't for the life of me work it out. When you precompile (prior to it crashing) do you see the fingerprinted image files appear in public/assets ?

Comment: The image is fingerprinted in pub/assets. this is very frustrating.

Comment: You could try adding .erb to the file, and temporarily using the asset_path helper to see if you get any more errors (clues).

Comment: that did not do anything either. perhaps this is a sass-rails issue.